# Административная панель Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.x, django-admin

Как поменять название столбцов, вместо "company", "series" отобразить "компания", "линейка" (смотрите скрин ниже, красным выделил то, что надо отобразить иначе), и тоже самое сделать в фильтре сбоку, то есть вместо  "company" отобразить "компания"?

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

class CPUAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('company', 'series', 'model', 'type_delievery')
    search_fields = ['company', 'series__name', 'model', 'type_delievery']
    list_filter = ('company', 'type_delievery', 'count', 'socket__name')

admin.site.register(models.CPU, CPUAdmin)
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Прописать нужные verbose_name в модели

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите у полей модели `CPUAdmin` параметр `verbose_name`

Например

```py
class CPUAdmin(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(verbose_name='Компания', max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 2):

По хорошему, писать на русском прямо в коде неверно.

Перевод должен делаться соответствующими инструментами

В модели, да, добавляете verbose_name, обернутую в gettext функцию

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class CPU(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('company'), max_length=64)
```

потом в командной строке запускаете генерацию файла переводов .po

```
python manage.py makemessages -l ru-RU
```

django генерит файлик со всеми словами, требующими перевода

...locale/ru-RU/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

его можно редактировать обычным редактором, но лучше взять [Poedit](https://poedit.net/)

после добавления переводов

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

и вуаля, включаем в settings нужный язык и радуемся.

[дока](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/)